# How can to show more than one form value in a alert?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm submitting a form which its deleting record.

It's a simple checkbox, if the user check the box then
that record will be deleted from the table , which works.

What I would like to do its have a alert box which shows
the name of the person(s) they are deleting before and then they confirm it which then it will be deleted.

Right now im using ajax to show the alert but its only showing the first record I check ,
It still deleting all the records but I would like it to show all all the names before the user confirm it.
How would I be able to accomplish this?

```
function sub_keys()
    {    
    alert_string='Are you sure you want to delete ';
    var con=confirm( alert_string + document.getElementById("name_id").value + '?');
               if(con)
               {
               var formData = $("#confrm_key").serializeArray();

                var URL = 'quality_time_delete_table2.cfc?method=getkeyDetail';

                more code.....
    }
```

form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="name_Id" id="name_id" value="#emp_namefirst# #emp_namelast# ">
```

Comment: I would not use `alert()` or `confirm()`. But you would loop over the results before concatenating them into a single String. I would create a confirmation box by using absolute positioning on top of a relative position.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class in your checkboxes and use js `querySelectorAll` and `Array.prototype.map()`:

```js
var text = document.querySelectorAll('.name');
var values = [].map.call(text, function(obj) {
  return obj.innerHTML;
});
confirm(values);
```

```html
<div class="name">test1</div>
<div class="name">test2</div>
<div class="name">test3</div>
<div class="name">test4</div>
```

And one example close to your needs:

```js
function deletePeople() {
    var text = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked');
    var values = [].map.call(text, function (obj) {
        return obj.value;
    });
    var res = confirm(values);
    res ? alert("records deleted") : alert("no action");
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="test1" />
<input type="checkbox" value="test2" />
<input type="checkbox" value="test3" />
<input type="checkbox" value="test4" />
<input type="button" onclick="deletePeople();return false;" value="Delete" />
```

Also keep in mind that `id` must be unique.

References:

[Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

[document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll)